# models and forms in one class (Django)

Tags: python, django, forms, radio-button, models

I am new to Django and Python and wanted to ask you how I can get models and forms in one class. I want to use Radio Buttons, EmailField, DateTimeField so I need really both (models and forms) :

```
class Post(models.Model):

    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'male'), (False, 'female'))

    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender= models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

Of course I can not write class Post(models.Model) if I use models and forms but I dont know what to do to dispaly both in my view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Models and forms are different things, although you can get a form from a model by using ModelForm. Exactly what are you going you achieve?

Comment: Just want to use Radio buttons in form to display. All models appear in website and I am able to integrate Drop down using models but I want to use Radio buttons instead. What can I do to display the Radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think you need to do this in the model. If you want to customize the form representation of a model, then you simply define a custom modelform and override the relevant field:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, widget=RadioSelect,
                                    coerce=bool)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```